# DAL layer implimintation with NHibernate and making it generic

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics, data-access-layer

I am building a DAL layer for fun and learing (some fun i have), and i want it to be the generic as can be.
Is it smart to create a DAL manager that can create the Dal specific by using the generic `<>`.
For example i have a class `Customer` with the some property lets say `Name` but it does not matter.
and for creating the specific Dal class we will do this :

```
IDal customerDal = DalManager<ICustomer>.GetDal();
```

i imaging using `IoC` under the hood and so on.
1. Do you think it is a good idea ?
2. Is there a an example project some where on the web (a good one, i found some bad ones).

Thank you very much 
you are all awesome.

Comment: This is an impossible question to answer. You want to know if it's a good idea but you've given us next to no details on how you plan to implement it (except you want to use generics, and *maybe* and IoC container). It sounds like you haven't actually planned this out yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, this is a bad idea.  NHibernate is already an abstraction over your database, you don't need another one.
2. See http://code.google.com/p/nhjump/ for an example of the Repository pattern being used with NHibernate